# Firebase authentication and Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement Sign-up and Sign-in feature using Google firebase and Springboot.
The request from React app will hit my springboot and get redirected to firebase.

I am able to create a user from Springboot application using below code (This is kind of Sign-up feature)

```
        UserRecord.CreateRequest req = new UserRecord.CreateRequest();
        req.setDisabled(false);
        req.setEmail("demouser123@email.com");
        req.setPassword("123456");
        req.setDisplayName("demouser");
        instance.createUser(req); // Creates user
```

[Registered new user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQb5x.png)

How can I implement Sign-in feature where I receive token from Firebase to Springboot and that will be sent to my React app.
(I want to avoid directly connecting to firebase from React app)

[Flow I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0DK4.png)

Using firebase-admin v8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sign-in to Firebase Authentication through the Admin SDK. What you can do is call the REST API to [sign in with email and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) in your Spring Boot code, and then return the ID token you get from there to your client.